# Are there countries where a group is elected instead of a single leader

Tags: election, government

I mostly know about the French government and a couple of European ones. In all cases, you vote for a single leader (President, Prime minister, ...), which then forms his government by choosing their ministers.

In my opinion, it could be more efficient to vote directly for each minister, because you can't (and maybe shouldn't) ask a single man to have all the answers on many different topic (economy, education, health, justice, ...).

So my question is, are there any country in which you vote for each minister (or equivalent) instead of selecting a single party or leader?

Comment: In the UK, you vote for a MP who is (usually) affiliated with a party. The party with the most MP's then (typically) forms a government with their chosen leader as PM. The choice of ministers is still up to the PM.

Comment: In Germany, you vote for MPs and approximately half the seats are given directly to persons, the other half to members of parties. However it is common for several parties to form coalitions and these parties then each get a few government departments.

Comment: The title does not match the question. The title reads "Are there countries where a group is elected instead of a single leader" to which I would answer "yes, almost any country with a parliament with multiple parties". But the question body asks if there is a country in which *individual ministers* are elected. And ministers are single leaders, not groups. What exactly do you want to ask about?

Comment: Parliamentary systems are like this. UK as already pointed out. Canada is another. There are several.